# set font with ColumnText

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, itext

i try to set the font with ColumnText, but it's not working.

```
PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;

BaseFont title = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA_BOLD, BaseFont.WINANSI, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);

cb.SetFontAndSize(title, 10); //10 is the font size
string text = "this is sample of long long long paragraph..";

ColumnText column1 = new ColumnText(cb);

column1.SetSimpleColumn(255, 145, 600, 100);         
Paragraph p;
p = new Paragraph(new Paragraph(text));
column1.Go();
```

i tried this code, it's not working as well:

```
p = new Paragraph(new Paragraph(text, cb.SetFontAndSize(title, 10)));
```

Error Message: `The best overloaded method match for 'iTextSharp.text.Paragraph.Paragraph(string, iTextSharp.text.Font)' has some invalid arguments`

Can someone advice me? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You passing an instance of Paragraph to the constructor of a second Paragraph.

Try:

```
BaseFont title = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA_BOLD, BaseFont.WINANSI, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
Font titleFont = new Font(title, 10, Font.BOLD, Color.BLACK);
p = new Paragraph(text, titleFont);
```

Comment: thank for the reply, but it's not working as well, same error message

Answer (score 1):

I know that this question already has a (correct) answer, but I want to add that many things in the original code are wrong. I'll copy/paste the code and explain why they are wrong.

```
// This is right: if you want to use ColumnText, you need a PdfContentByte
PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;
// This may not be necessary if you merely need Helvetica Bold in a Paragraph, but it's not incorrect.
BaseFont title = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA_BOLD, BaseFont.WINANSI, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
// YOU DON'T NEED THE FOLLOWING LINE. PLEASE REMOVE IT!
cb.SetFontAndSize(title, 10); //10 is the font size
// OK, you're just defining a string
string text = "this is sample of long long long paragraph..";
// OK, you're defining a ColumnText object and defining the rectangle
ColumnText column1 = new ColumnText(cb);
column1.SetSimpleColumn(255, 145, 600, 100);         
// OK, you're defining a paragraph
Paragraph p;
// This is strange: why do you nest paragraphs?
// Why don't you use the font?
p = new Paragraph(new Paragraph(text));
// You are forgetting a line here: where do you add the paragraph to the column?
// Nothing will happen here:
column1.Go();
```

This is how I would rewrite the code:

```
PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;
ColumnText column1 = new ColumnText(cb);
column1.SetSimpleColumn(255, 145, 600, 100); 
Font font = new Font(FontFamily.HELVETICA_BOLD);
string text = "this is sample of long long long paragraph..";
Paragraph p = new Paragraph(text, font);
column1.AddElement(p);
column1.Go();
```